# Hash and un-hash a key with Google Script

Tags: hash, google-apps-script

I need to hash a key and I found this method provided by `Google Script`: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#computeHmacSha256Signature%28String,String%29

But how can I un-hash the key computed with that method?

Here is what I've tried to do:

```
  var my_key = "g1w9625bf43bfd91s6c2095c1w160699a59m72t"
  var hash = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature("this", my_key);

  var un_hash = Utilities.base64Decode(hash);
```

The hash function works, but un_hash returns me `Could not decode string`.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hashing can't be reversed. You shouldn't be able to un-hash a hash. 
As you can see in the image below, it is possible that multiple values have the same hash-value.

If you calculated the hash as being "02", you could never know whether this hash was calculated on "John Smith" or "Sandra Dee". The information just isn't there.

[image]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hash_table_4_1_1_0_0_1_0_LL.svg